# How to walk over the parts of a word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

For debug purposes and out of curiousity I want to investigate the structure of a word document. As a practical application I'd imagine a VBA-based converter from Word to some other format.

*The problem*: how do I understand what is stored inside a paragraph?

For example:

[image]

With help of VBA I want to find that the document consists of:

- the letter A
- the button B
- the letter C
- the end of the paragraph

I tried to look at the document character-by-character:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ActiveDocument.Range.End - 1
        Set r = ActiveDocument.Range(i, i + 1)
        Debug.Print "The symbol: " & r.Text
    Next
End Sub
```

The result is:

```
The symbol: A
The symbol: 
The symbol:  
The symbol: C
The symbol: O
The symbol: N
The symbol: T
The symbol: R
The symbol: O
The symbol: L
The symbol:  
The symbol: F
The symbol: o
The symbol: r
The symbol: m
The symbol: s
The symbol: .
The symbol: C
The symbol: o
The symbol: m
The symbol: m
The symbol: a
The symbol: n
The symbol: d
The symbol: B
The symbol: u
The symbol: t
The symbol: t
The symbol: o
The symbol: n
The symbol: .
The symbol: 1
The symbol:  
The symbol: \
The symbol: s
The symbol:  
The symbol: 
The symbol: 
The symbol: 
The symbol: C
The symbol:
```

The button is spread over a range. I can't find a range object property which would allow me to distinguish between the button and the usual text.

Comment: There are many ways to do this looping. The button is a `Field` that can be identified using the `Range.Fields` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Get the document's WordOpenXML. Traversing that would be the best way to pick things up as they occur. Word's object model isn't built to do what you want.

```
Document.Content.WordOpenXML
```

gives you the WordOpenXML that defines the document in the OPC flat file format - as a string.

Or you can work on closed documents using the Open XML SDK.

The ECMA documentation on Office Open XML explains what each element represents and how it all links together.